# How to load geojson files from a folder js, using esri

Tags: javascript, json, geojson, esri

I am trying to show some POI into the mao I am using I totaly get no error but still not getting any resualts, I have made a special way too load them but still cant get it.

I made a way to the map and started adding the files and the folders in a way I cant rellay explain and made a new path that ledas to them, and that what I want to use toload the info in them, btw they are gejson but I thingk they are the sam as json files.

```
var map;
var file;
var fileIndex = 10;

require(["esri/map",
  "esri/geometry/Point",
  "esri/geometry/Polygon",
  "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
  "esri/InfoTemplate",
  "esri/graphic",
  "esri/Color",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/domReady!"],
  function (Map, Point, Polygon, GraphicLayer, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, InfoTemp, Graphic, Color, On) {
    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
      basemap: "streets",
      center: [17.451444710859978, 60.60193360270525],
      zoom: 12,
      sliderStyle: "small"
    });
    loadPOIData();

    graphics = new GraphicLayer();
    map.addLayer(graphics);

    marker = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();

    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", loadFile);
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_11_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_12_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_13_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_14_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_15_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_16_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_17_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_18_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_19_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_20_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_21_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_Slinga_11_1_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_Slinga_12_1_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_Slinga_12_2_inkl_kolkoja_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Etapp_Slinga_21_1_wgs84.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Biking_elevation161008.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Walk_elevation_123547.json");
    loadFile("JSON/Walk_elevation_151851.json");
        
        
    function loadFile(file) {
        require(["dojo/request"], function (request) {
          request.get(file, {
            handleAs: "json"
          }).then(TrailData);
        });
      }
      
    
    
  });
  


function TrailData(jsonData){
    var dummyString = "";
    var polylineJson = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];
    
    var ehee = 0;
    dojo.forEach(jsonData.posts, function(posts){
        var lng = posts.longitude;
        var lat = posts.latitude;
        
        var pathindex = posts.PathIndex;
        
        polylineJson[pathindex].push([lng, lat]);
        var polylineAtt = {
            "title": ehee + " " + file,
            "content": lng + " " + lat,
            "category": 6,
            "pathindex": pathindex
        }
        
        
        
        graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(new esri.geometry.Point(lng, lat, new esri.SpatialReference(4326)), new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(), polylineAtt));
        graphics.graphics[graphics.graphics.length - 1].hide();
        ehee++;
        
    });
    var line = new esri.geometry.Polyline(polylineJson);
    let lineSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.Color([0,0,0]),3);
    
    
    var polygraphicAtt = {
        "title": fileIndex,
        "content": file,
        "category": 5
    }
    
    let polyLineGraphic = new esri.Graphic(line, lineSymbol, polygraphicAtt);
    graphics.add(polyLineGraphic);
}
// Remove the existing POI data loading code
// ...

function loadPOIData() {
    var folderPath = "POI/"; // Path to the folder containing the GeoJSON files
    var poiFiles = [
      "Paddla_Balerbyhallan.geojson",
      "Paddla_Balletsportklubben.geojson",
      "Paddla_Brattnaleset.geojson",
      "Paddla_Dragsheden_olest.geojson",
      "Paddla_Dragsheden_valest.geojson",
      "Paddla_Goleknaset.geojson",
      "Paddla_Olesta_Camping.geojson",
      "Paddla_Olesta_norr.geojson",
      "Paddla_Olesta_valest.geojson",
      "Paddla_Sandolen.geojson",
      "Paddla_Skekarsbo.geojson",
      "Paddla_Stralengnas.geojson",


    ];
  
    for (var i = 0; i < poiFiles.length; i++) {
      var filePath = folderPath + poiFiles[i];
      loadFile1(filePath);
    }
  }
  
  function loadFile1(file1) {
    dojo.xhrGet({
      url: file1,
      handleAs: "json",
      load: function (jsonData) {
        showPoiPoints(jsonData);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error loading file:", error);
      }
    });
  }
  
  function showPoiPoints(poiData) {
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol({
      "url": "bilder/poi.png",
      "width": 15,
      "height": 15
    });
  
    dojo.forEach(poiData.featureS, function (poiFeature) {
      var name = poiFeature.properties.name;
      var longitude = poiFeature.geometry.coordinates[0];
      var latitude = poiFeature.geometry.coordinates[1];
  
      var point = new esri.geometry.Point(longitude, latitude);
  
      var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol);
      graphic.setInfoTemplate(new esri.InfoTemplate("Point Of Interest", "<b>" + name + "</b>"));
      graphics.add(graphic);
    });
  }
```